# How to make JOIN Function in SQL work according to my homework requirements?

Tags: sql, join

**Description:**

Please modify next two SQL commands for resolving of followed task:

Adjust a relationship between tables ORDERS and CUSTOMERS, where the ID field from CUSTOMERS tables should be a primary key, and the ID_CUSTOMER field from ORDERS table should be a foreign key field. After removing a customer, all his orders should also be removed.

**My work:**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (id int primary key, firstname varchar(30), 
    lastname varchar(30), ADDRESS VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ID INT primary key, 
   PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(30), 
   PRODUCT_PRICE FLOAT,
   DATE_ORDER DATE,
   ID_CUSTOMER INT,
   AMOUNT INT);

ALTER TABLE ORDERS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUSTOMER)
REFERENCES ORDERS (ID)
;
```

**Expected result (according to homework system):**

```
CUSTOMERS|1
ORDERS|2
DELETE ONE RECORD IN CUSTOMERS
CUSTOMERS|0
ORDERS|0
```

Why so? And what am I suppose to do to remove the customer?

> After removing a customer, all his orders should also be removed.

Comment: What did you learn by reading the material you were supposed to read, or any introduction to declaring FKs, or hits googling with 'site:stackoverflow.com' for the many other times this basic question has obviously been asked? [ask].

Comment: let me give you a secret. The community doesn't appreciate the homeworks too much, and expects you to show clearly the consumed effort till preparation of the question.

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with JOIN? (It doesn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (id int primary key,
    firstname varchar(30),
    lastname varchar(30),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ID INT primary key,
   PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(30),
   PRODUCT_PRICE FLOAT,
   DATE_ORDER DATE,
   ID_CUSTOMER INT,
   AMOUNT INT,
   FOREIGN KEY(ID_CUSTOMER) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Answer (score 0):

a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` will cause the record to be deleted when the record it references is deleted.

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUSTOMER)
REFERENCES ORDERS (ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```